# Angular-ui-bootstrap accordion and collapse animation not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

On the angular-ui-bootstrap [demo/docs page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/), the [accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) and [collapse](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) directives are both animated when clicking on an item.

However the animations do not work in the plunker demos also found on that page. Is some dependency missing or is it a possible bug?

(tested in chrome / firefox )

**UPDATE:**

I updated to **version 0.14.3** on 2015-10-29 and everything works great now. Thank you to the angularUI team for all the hard work!

Comment: This is not a bug, on version 0.13 you need to include `ngAnimate` in your application. Also, the plunkers are working with animation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug on version 0.13 of bootstrap-ui
Just change back to 0.12 like below:

`<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>`

Comment: Correct! I was on version 0.13. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The answer provided by @mvermand below is now the correct one.

Answer (score 23):

As of version 0.13, **you need to include ngAnimate** in your application:

1. `bower install angular-animate --save`
2. Add script reference to index.html (for example with `grunt wiredep`):

   ```
   <script src="vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
   ```
3. Add the module reference to your Angular application, for example:

   ```
   angular.module('app', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate']);
   ```

Comment: Ya. I had ng-animate included at the time. This was an internal issue with version 0.13.xx that has since been resolved.

Comment: After adding ngAnimate it started working for me. I am using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.3/#/accordion

Comment: I am using version 2.5.x of ui-bootstrap, previously I was using 0.12.x. The animation worked when I was using 0.12.x, I had included the ui-bootstrap-tpls separately as mentioned above. After upgrading it appears the author automatically includes the ui-bootstrap-tpls. So that wasn't the problem. However, it wasn't until I added ngAnimate that it worked correctly. Thanks for this! It saved my bacon.